# No of ways to arrange books

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four  different  mathematics  books,  six  different  physics  books,  and  two  different  chemistry books are to be arranged on a shelf.  How many different arrangements are possible if only the mathematics books must stand together?
Can anyone help me please?
I thought of inclusion and exclusion principle

Our sir has given answer saying that  no of ways to arrange math book is $4!$ and considering math books as one there are total $9$ books so total number of ways is $9!$*$4!$ .

*Here is my question*: I am confused that in this way there will be a case where physics or chemistry books will be standing together, but question says that *only math books* should be as a whole. Please help me.Tommorow is my exam.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Are you sure that you chose a right forum?

Comment: It seems like you are just asking for someone to do your homework for you.   That is not the purpose of this site.  Please read my comment again.

Comment: @saulspatz now i have edited, please help me

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.  $9!\cdot4!$ is the answer if the math books are required to stand together and no restriction is placed on the chemistry and physics books.  The "only" means that such a requirement is placed only on the math books.  I agree that your interpretation is possible, but it's not how I would interpret it.  This is more of an English question that a math question, really.  I wouldn't worry about for study purposes. If a question like this comes up on the exam, ask the proctor what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $9!\cdot 4!$ counts the number of ways of positioning the books, with the restriction that the math books are standing together, and *that this number also contains situations where the physics books or the chemistry books stand together*.

You are interpreting the sentence ''...only the mathematics books must stand together.'' as meaning that the physics books cannot stand together and likewise for the chemistry books. I understand this interpretation, but I don't think it is the intended one, especially when seeing your teacher's answer.

I think the sentence can be sharpened by writing it as ''...the only demand is that the mathematics books must stand together.'', and I also think that this is what was the intention.

Comment: Thank you for clarrifaction